# Reinstalling app from App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have a app **myapp.appV5.0** (Support from IOS 5 & IOS 6), and we gave an update say **maybe.app V6**(support from IOS 7 & greater)

In my iPhone i have IOS 6, my mistake i deleted my app, is it possible to get the app again????
(some where from purchase tab or from iCloud etc).

Please help me in this business scenario.

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

**Details**
Current app version:  maybe.app V6
Supporting IOS : IOS 7 & greater
Device: iPhone4 (IOS 5)

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=get%20older%20version%20of%20ios%20app

Comment: @iBhavin Thank you. How to verify that older compatible version is available in App Store, if so how long it will be available